Unable to create symlink: File name too long in NixOS
I created two repositories.
The first contains a web application in Nuxt which I mainly run and develop on a NixOS machine.
The second one contains hard symlinks to Markdown files which I edit using the Obsidian note-taking app on my Windows machine.
I'm using mklink to create the symlinks.
My intention is to use the second repository as a submodule to feed the contents to the Nuxt site. I'm using symlinks to keep my Obsidian vault and the site contents somewhat separated and to selectively serve certain files when ready. Symlinks allow me to update the contents from Obsidian directly if they need editing.
The second repository works as expected, whenever I create a hard symlink and push the contents to GitHub, they update as expected.
The main issue is that I can't initialize the submodule on the first repository on my NixOS machine where I work.
The error reads as follows:
error: unable to create symlink file1.md: File name too long
If I clone and initialize the submodule on my Windows machine it works as expected, but I wish to not work on the Nuxt site on my Windows machine.
I have tried running git config --system core.longpaths true and also cloning the repo with git clone -c core.longpaths=true <repo-url>
Any advice is welcome!

How long is the path where you're trying to create the symlink?

The complete path is /home/user10/writing/nuxt-ui-app/test1.md  I even tried with just 1.md to no avail.
